# how to use XMLTextWriter to write XML node at a specified position

Tags: c#, xml, xmltextreader, xmltextwriter

I have an xml file likes below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Book>
  <Title>Title</Title>
  <Content>Content</Content>
</Book>
```

I want to write a new node after 'Content', I know how to use XMLDocument to do that, is there a way to use XMLTextWriter to do that?

Comment: please mention the language you are using i.e. C#, java etc.

Comment: You want to modify the XML document, so why're you opposed to dealing with the XML document entity? XMLTextWriter is for writing an existing XML document entity to a file, not for modifying something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write the whole Xml document, i.e. all elements and attributes and attribute values by using the `XmlTextWriter`. After you've written the `<Content>` element, you can write your additional element.

Something like this:

```
writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteStartElement("Book");
writer.WriteStartElement("Title");
writer.WriteString("Title");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteStartElement("Content");
writer.WriteString("Content");
writer.WriteEndElement();
// insert your new data here
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
```